# Mongodb percentage difference of aggregate max and last values

Tags: mongodb

```
  db['temperatures'].aggregate([
{ $match: {    create_date: { // 200 minutes ago (from now)
    $gt: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 200)
}}},
{$group: { 
                _id: "Temp",
            temp: {$max: "$temp"},
            last: {$last: "$temp"},
            //how can i get the percentage difference?
        }}
])
```

How can i find the percentage difference of these two values?

Comment: Something like `{"addFields:{"pd"{$multiply:[{$divide:[{$subtract:["$temp", "$last"]}, "$last"]}, 100]}}}`. Add as last stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will work,

```
db['temperatures'].aggregate([
        { $match: {    create_date: {
            $gt: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 200)
        }}},
        {$group: { 
                        _id: "Temp",
                    temp: {$max: "$temp"},
                    last: {$last: "$temp"},
        }},
       {$project:{
         _id:'$_id',
         temp:'$temp',
         last:'$last',
         percentage_diff:{$multiply:[{$divide:[{$subtract:["$temp", "$last"]}, "$last"]}, 100]}
        }}
    ])
```

Comment: this works great!. What happens if I want to take to compare the mid temperature with the last? How should i enter  ($max + $min) / 2 in the grouping of the data?

Comment: db['temperatures'].aggregate([
        { $match: {    create_date: {
            $gt: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 200)
        }}},
        {$group: { 
                        _id: "Temp",
                    temp: {$max: "$temp"},avg:{$avg:'$temp'},
                    last: {$last: "$temp"},
        }},
       {$project:{
         _id:'$_id',
         temp:'$temp',
         last:'$last',
         percentage_diff:{$multiply:[{$divide:[{$subtract:["$temp", "$avg"]}, "$last"]}, 100]}
        }}
    ])